# what does "lift the way changing a button " mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> So here’s what I’m starting to take away… Changing the headline may not ‘guarantee’ a valid, measurable and **meaningful lift the way changing a button seems to**. So if the goal is to move people through our funnels, which might we start to think is more important: the headline, or the button?

I dont know what does not guarantee here.
changing the headline may not guarantee lift in the button?

Comment: Without more of the conversation we can only guess.  But my guess is that the ***lift*** refers to increased traffic being driven to the site and that more *lift* is generated, i.e., more people click-thru to the button's href, when the button text is changed rather than when the headline text is changed.

Comment: I don't want to move through their funnels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing a comma that would clarify a little better: *Changing the headline may not ‘guarantee’ a valid, measurable and meaningful lift[,] the way changing a button seems to.*

So what it's saying is that "Changing the headline may not cause [a result] [in] the way that changing a button seems to [cause a result]."

Or, moving things around, I believe it is saying, "Changing the button seems to cause a definite increase in people clicking it and reading our web pages. Changing the headlines that link to those web pages may not have such a definite increase. To get people to read our web pages, we need to figure out which one to focus on: the headline, or the button?"